# How to specify initial position of browser when viewing SVG file or embedded SVG code

Tags: html, svg, anchor

I have an SVG file with a network diagram (rectangle with arrows connecting the rectangles). It is much larger that the browser's viewport. The logical starting point when reading the diagram is at a rectangle near the center of the diagram. I would like the initial view to be centered on this particular rectangle so the user doesn't have to hunt it down.

I am aware of the HTML anchor tag that allows you to open a webpage at a particular location. It is my understanding the  tag within the SVG file does not work the same way. Is there another way of controlling the initial position of the browser to start at an element of an SVG file? I don't mind having to embed the SVG code within an html file if there is a solution that would require that.

Comment: Please include some code to show what you have done so far, it will help us be able to answer your question.

Comment: Use the viewBox attribute for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that seems to work with Google Chrome, Firefox and Android WebView is to use `window.scroll(x,y)` in JavaScript. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="5000" height="5000">

    <rect id="rect1" x="3000" y="3000" width="200" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var rect1 = document.getElementById("rect1");
        var x = 3100 - window.innerWidth/2;
        var y = 3050 - window.innerHeight/2;
        window.scroll(x,y);
    </script>
</svg>
```